# jQuery wrap table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to wrap a set of consecutive table rows using jQuery, but when I try to target them, it's not finding the rows I expected it to.

```
$("tr.row1").next("tr:lt(4)").wrapAll("<tr class='wrapped'><td><table></table></td></tr>");​
```

I'm not sure how to properly explain this, so please look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/uqp6H/

Instead of wrapping row2 row3 row4 and row5, it is wrapping the next four row2's.

Comment: Did you mean `$('tr[class^="row"]:lt(4)').wrapAll("<tr class='wrapped'><td><table></table></td></tr>");​​​​​​​​​​`?

Comment: Are you trying to wrap all four or just the first row? What if the table has more than 4, do you want the first 4 only?

Comment: I think he's trying to wrap all except the first row

Comment: I want it to wrap rows 2,3,4,5.

Comment: Please do transfer all the code from JSFiddle to here. As your post stands, the only code we consider is `$("tr.row1").next("tr:lt(4)").wrapAll("<tr class='wrapped'><td><table></table></td></tr>");​` and therefore we cannot help you.

Comment: @double-beep This question was asked and answered in 2012. You're a little late buddy. I don't have the code in question anymore. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
​$('tr.row2').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.row5 + *').andSelf().wrapAll("<tr class='wrapped'><td colspan='3'><table></table></td></tr>");
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This wraps from row2 to row5. (It also sets the colspan of the wrapper to 3 - if you need this).

http://jsfiddle.net/g59mg/

Comment: Yes! This is perfect, thanks so much! Can you explain what the + * does in nextUntil?

Comment: nextUntil selects `exclusively`. This means it doesn't select the first  and last element. `+ *` *shifts* the selection "one element further". This way you also get `tr.row5` itself. `andSelf()` then adds the first element to the collection.

Comment: @Jables: it's the "next adjacent selector": http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/

Answer (score 0):

This should select the rows you need, but then your wrapping element is screwing up the structure

As a test, I am just selecting the first four rows and applying the color red to them which works fine.

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $("tr",this).slice(1,5).css('color','red')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $("tr:gt(0)",this).wrapAll("<tr class='wrapped'><td colspan='3'><table></table></td></tr>");  
})
```